# QFT for gifted amateur example 2.5

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform

From the QFT for gifted amateur [book](https://indico.cern.ch/event/957763/contributions/4025879/attachments/2117913/3598224/Quantum%20Field%20Theory%20for%20the%20Gifted%20Amateur-Oxford%20University%20Press%20%282014%29.pdf) pg. 25, example 2.5:

> We begin by Fourier transforming both $x_j$ and $p_j$ by writing
> $$x_j=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_k\tilde{x}_k e^{ikja},$$
> $$p_j=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_k\tilde{p}_k e^{ikja},$$ and equivalently
> of course $$\tilde{x}_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_j x_j e^{-ikja},$$
> $$\tilde{p}_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_j p_j e^{-ikja}.$$ We impose
> periodic boundary conditions forcing $e^{ikja}=e^{ik(j+N)a}$. The wave
> vector $k$ therefore takes the values $2\pi m/Na$, where $m$ is an
> integer in the range $-N/2 < m < N/2$ . Note that $$\sum_j
>  e^{ikja}=N\delta_{k,0}.$$

How can it be shown explicitly that $\sum_j e^{ikja}=N\delta_{k,0}$?

Comment: This series is geometric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So $\sum_{j=1}^N e^{ikja}= \sum_{j=1}^N e^{2 \pi i m j /N}$ where $m$ is an integer.

The sum of a geometric series $ar,...ar^n$ is $\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$ for $r \neq 1$. In our context, $r=e^{2\pi i m /N}$ and $n=N$ which leads to $r^N=1$. Therefore, the numerator of our geometric sum and therefore the geometric sum itself is zero unless $r=1$, which happens when $m=0$ or equivalently $k=0$. For $k=0$, it is easily seen that every term in the series is $1$, giving us the required result.